# Xlib functions and sleep

Tags: c++, xlib

Am a new user to C++,

Am trying to design a UI, Which has the following methods,

```
XtRealizeWidget
```

And at one point i need to use `XWithdrawWindow` method.

My question is, in all examples i see, there is a `sleep()` code used with methods like, `XWithdrawWindow` or `XMapWindow` or `XMoveWindow`

i.e whenever the above methods are used a sleep() call is also made.

What is the use of Sleep here? Why we need sleep?

An example for above scenario can be found at ,http://slist.lilotux.net/linux/xlib/window-operations.c

Edit:

Without these sleep , `XWithdrawWindow` is not working properly always.

Comment: In the code referenced by your link, the `sleep` calls are added to add some animation to the transformations with the created window.

Comment: I strongly suggest these days to avoid coding in Xlib (you'll need many months even for a simple task)... Since you mention C++, why can't you use [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) ???

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Just to learn basics of Xlib i started coding in that.Yes, i'll definitely opt for any of the one you suggested when there is a real need.

Comment: Even simple things will take months in Xlib. And `XtRealizeWidget` is *not* Xlib (but the obsolete Xt toolkit)